# Extract first character of a workbook and copy over to another workbook using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for a way to solve my problem by using MID, Split I still couldn't get the results.

I am trying to extract the first character from one excel sheet and copy to another excel workbook using VBA.

```
strChar = Range("G2")
Workbooks("InputA.xls").Worksheets("Sheet0").Mid(strChar, 1, 1).Copy _
        ("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range ("F2")
```

I am not familiar with VBA but I have looked up MID,LEFT,RIGHT and Spilt but it seems that I am unable to write the correct code out

For example in range("G2") and its value is (B) EEO324324 But I only need to extract the character B and copy to another workbook

Comment: just as a quick clarification will all first characters be in brackets like your example states? So (B) or (F) or (2)? Also will the character be extracted from a different workbook? If so, you need to open and activate it first.

Comment: No only the first row will be like (B) but I only need to extract B out. Second row onward will be like A 231243245 but I only need to extract A. Yes it will be extracted to another workbook, I did activate the other workbook as well but still couldn't get the result.

Comment: So the thing that would be important to know is whether the data follows a pattern, so you can base the code on that. E.g. If its always in () you could use `mid(var,2,1)`. Since that's not the case is it always an upper case alphabetical like A or B? Without knowing that it will be hard to make something that works for everything. So if 1 cell has `(7)` and the next has `B`  you wouldn't be able to extract the character by either type or position. Is the total number of characters always the same maybe?

Comment: Only the first row will be different but the rest it is the same

Comment: in that case go for what @Tim Williams, provided you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range ("F2").Value = _
           Left(Workbooks("InputA.xls").Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("G2").value, 1)
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your code it works but this only gives me the first character of the cell. What should I change if I need to extract the 2nd character of the cell instead? Thank you so much

Comment: `Mid([cell ref here],2,1)`

Comment: Thank you so much now I know where is the problem. I didn't use value